Movie about a little black boy and a girl he has a crush on
All I really remember about this movie, that I watched when I was about 8 years old, was mainly that it was an old black and white movie. It's an American movie, maybe from the 1930s between 1950s.
It was about a little black boy's life. It mainly showed his daily life being at school which was a very small country looking class with all black students and a black teacher. There was a lighter skinned girl in the class who was very sweet and nice, that the boy had a crush on, but did not want to really show it.
One day, when they were doing a play, I think Sleeping Beauty or Snow White maybe, the girl was pretending to be asleep but when it was time for her to get up, she wasn't awakening. The little boy got the teacher's attention and they took her home. The next scene was at the girl's house and they told the boy she was very sick and always has been. 
Then one of the last scenes showed the grave of the little girl who died and the boy was mad and started crying.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question.
